# how can I hide sub sub headings from main menu?

Tags: menu, submenu, sidebar

I am using ultimo theme. I have a main menu that has a main heading, with sub sub headings. I added the sub sub headings in the category tab of the admin panel.

Basically...

Apparel (heading)
Womens Clothing (sub heading)
t shirts (sub sub heading)
pants (sub sub heading)
skirts (sub sub heading)
etc....

I would like to hide the sub sub headings (tshirts, pants, skirts) from main menu so that it is not too clustered when a customer is hovering over headings. I Don't want to de-activate those headings because I need them inorder for the sidebar navigation to display them under the womens clothing page. Is there a way for me to just hide them from the main menu?

Answer (score 2):

If you go to Catalog -> Manage Categories and navigate to the categories you don't want shown (in this case tshirts, pants, skirts) and scroll all the way down on the General Information page to the bottom there is a dropdown box that will allow you to select whether or not the category is shown in the navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this ?
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/configuration-catalog-category-top-navigation